# the proper way to get properties from an XML?

Tags: java, xml, nodelist

I have the following XML file

```
 <requesting>
 <performing>
  <properties val1="foo"/>
  <properties val2="foo2"/>
 </requesting>
 </performing>
```

what is the proper Java way to fetch this data ? I'm getting confused :)

I'm trying the following..

after I loaded the xml file to a `Document dom`, I tried doing the following:

```
NodeList nl = dom.getElementsByTagName("requesting").item(0).getOwnerDocument().
             getElementsByTagName("performing").item(0).getOwnerDocument().
             getElementsByTagName("properties");
```

of course i get Null.

I'm missing something.. i don't know what... please assist me .

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Kfir

Comment: what was your idea of adding .getOwnerDocument() after getting your first node? What output did you expect from that?

Comment: May I suggest you use JAXB ?

Comment: JAXB looks interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

ok ok !! I found the solution to the problem!!

instead of getOwnerDocument() I needed to cast item(0) to Document.

means..

```
Document doc1 = (Document) dom.getElementsByTagName("requesting").item(0);
```

and so on...

that's it :) simple as that

thanks for your help guys :)